# Show all grouped results and sort

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, distinct

I have a table, like that one:

```
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 2 |
```

I would like to fetch it, but sorted and grouped. That is, I would like it grouped by the letter, but sorted by the highest sum of the group. Also, I want to show all entries within the group:

```
| C | 3 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 1 |
```

The order is that way because C has 3 and 2. 3+2=5, which is higher than 2+2=4 for A which in turn is higher than 2+1=3 for B.

I need to show all "grouped" letters because there are other columns that are distinct all of which I need shown.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the quick reply. I have the audacity, however, to inquire further.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `ip_log` WHERE `IP` IN
(SELECT `IP` FROM `ip_log` GROUP BY `IP` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `uid`) > 1)
GROUP BY `uid` ORDER BY `IP`
```

The letters in the upper description are `ip` (I need it grouped by the IP addresses) and the numbers are `timestamp` (I need it sorted by the sum (or just used as the sorting parameter)). Should I create a temporary table and then use the solution below?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "sorted by the sum" of your post-answer clarification? Sum of what?

Comment: Sorted by the sum of the timestamp values of the individual group, just like the letters are sorted by the sum of the numbers corresponding to a group of letters.

Comment: if the column is a timestamp I'm not sure about the behaviour of the SUM aggregation function so I don't quite follow

Comment: doesn't matter, I have already managed to solve this by saving it into a temporary table and then applying redfilter's method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select t.Letter, t.Value
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select Letter, sum(Value) as ValueSum
    from MyTable
    group by Letter
) ts on t.Letter = ts.Letter
order by ts.ValueSum desc, t.Letter, t.Value desc
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d137a/3)

Answer (score 0):

If your table's columns are `letter` and `number`, the way I would go around to doing this would be the following:

```
SELECT
    letter,
    GROUP_CONCAT(number ORDER BY number DESC),
    SUM(number) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY letter
ORDER BY total desc
```

What you will get, based on your example is the following:

```
| C | 3,2 | 5
| A | 2,2 | 4
| B | 2,1 | 3
```

You can then process that data to get the actual information you want/need.

If you still want the data in the format you requested originally, it is not possible with a single query. The reason for that is that you can't sort based on an aggregated data that you are not calculating in the same query (the SUM of the `number` column). So you will need to make a sub-query to calculate that and feed it back into the original query (disclaimer: untested query):

```
SELECT
    letter,
    number
FROM table
     JOIN (SELECT ltr, SUM(number) AS total FROM table GROUP BY letter) AS totals
          ON table.letter = totals.ltr
ORDER BY totals.total desc, letter desc, number desc
```